# One combined legend entry for multiple plots

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, matlab-figure

For some reason, I would like to plot the line and marker of the same data separately.

```
data1 = (1:1:10)';
data2 = (1:2:10);
figure(1);
plot(data1,data1,'or');
hold on;
plot(data2,data2,'-r');
legend('data');
```

However it will only display the legend for the first plot. And Matlab seems not to have option to manipulate the legend marker, color and linestyle.
[image]

How can I make legend like this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You can manipulate anything about legends using output arguments. Look for the `icons` variable when calling `legend` like so: `[h,icons,plots,str] = legend(___)`

Comment: Great! I must say that I did not understand you question very well except for the "manipulate legend marker part" haha :)

Comment: Yeah I'm deleting my answer as I seem to have misunderstood what the OP wants.  Good going @Benoit_11 !

Comment: I was exercising my mentalist skills @rayryeng :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 - lololol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to plot an **invisible** third plot (with almost no data to keep it fast) to define your legend:

```
data1 = (1:1:10)';
data2 = (1:2:10);
figure(1);
plot(data1,data1,'or'); hold on
plot(data2,data2,'-r'); hold on

%// legend plot
lp = plot(0,0,'-r','Marker','o','visible','off')
legend(lp,'data');
```

[image]

You need to pass the handle of that invisible plot to the `legend` command or you could even put the invisible plot into the legend:

```
legend(plot(0,0,'-r','Marker','o','visible','off'),'data');
```

If you need that more often, you can write a little helper function

```
style = @(LineStyle, MarkerStyle) plot(0,0,LineStyle,'Marker',MarkerStyle,'visible','off')
legend(style('-r','o'),'data');
```

... which you can customize with `'color'`, `'LineWidth'` or whatever you want.

It enables you to create fully customized legends with multiple entries independently from your actually data:

```
legend([style('-r','o'),style('-b','x'),style('-g','v')],{'1','2','3'});
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  BTW congrats on 10K!

Comment: Hey! Congrats on that!!

Comment: @thewaywewalk Congrats!