# MATLAB combined legend

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I need to combine several lines and dots on the legend. I found the solution to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818805/one-combined-legend-entry-for-multiple-plots). But there is a problem with the style of the line on the legend. I want to change the style to dashed line, but it does not work. Here is the code:

```
close all; clear; clc;
data2 = (5:2:10);
figure;
plot(data2,'--r'); hold on;

lp = plot(0,0,'--r','Marker','o','visible','off')
legend(lp,'data');
```

And the result of this code:
[image]

As you can see, the line style on the legend does not matches to the code `'r--'`.

Comment: What if you assign a legend to the first plot and use that handles to display the legend? Eg. `lp1 = plot(data2,'--r')` and then `legend(lp1,'data')` ? Maybe I misunderstood your question though

Comment: Yes, but it's not a combination of dots and lines in one legend entry.

Comment: Your example works for me. Are you sure you did not have a typo somewhere? However, why not just generate the plot directly, I mean it does not make sense to have a dashed line in the plot but a dashed and dotted line in the legend.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [One combined legend entry for multiple plots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818805/one-combined-legend-entry-for-multiple-plots)

Comment: Your exemple code also works for me (R2015b, Ubuntu).

Comment: patrik, the problem is that I have the dots and the line of the plot. And I want to show in one legend's entry dot and line. There are several dots and lines on plot.