# How to enlarge legend symbols?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

I am plotting my data as

```
%% Plot relative wrt to GT for each frame
XIndx_lsd = linspace(1,592, size( accu_RE_lsdSlam, 1 ) );
XIndx_my = linspace(1,592, size( accu_RE_my_method, 1 ) );

plot( XIndx_lsd, accu_RE_lsdSlam(:,5), 'r-.' )
hold on
plot( XIndx_my, accu_RE_my_method(:,5), 'b-' )
AX=legend( 'rel translation error for Kerl et al.', 'rel translation error for D-EA' );

xhand = xlabel( 'Frame#' );
yhand = ylabel( '||trans(E_i)||_2 (in mm)' );
axis( [1 600 0 16] );

set(gca,'FontSize', 78);
set(xhand,'fontsize',78)
set(yhand,'fontsize',78)
```

I am able to get large font size. My question is how to get a large symbol size. See marked figure below.

[image]

Comment: Is there still something missing? If not please consider accepting the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using an older [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818805/one-combined-legend-entry-for-multiple-plots/28819664#28819664) of mine, which suggests to actually replot the legend symbols,

```
plot( 0:10, 0:10, 'b-' ); hold on;
plot( 0:10, 10:-1:0, 'r-' ); hold on;

%// Legend Style
style = @(LineStyle,LineWidth) plot(0,0,LineStyle,'LineWidth',LineWidth,'visible','off')
AX = legend( [style('b-',20),style('r-',20)], {'      Legend entry 2','      Legend entry 1'}, 'box','off' );

xlim([0 10]); ylim([0 10]);
xhand = xlabel( 'Frame#' );
yhand = ylabel( '||trans(E_i)||_2 (in mm)' );

set(gca,'FontSize', 28);
set(xhand,'fontsize',28)
set(yhand,'fontsize',28)
```

[image]