# How to increase marker size of the legend in scatter plot in MATLAB 2014b?

Tags: matlab, legend, scatter, legend-properties, matlab-hg2

I found marker size in the scatter plot and the legend is different in MATLAB 2014b. I searched & found some solution from earlier version of MATLAB, which are not applicable in the latest version. In my current version, the marker size in legend is so small that it is hardly distinguishable. Any help?

```
figure; 
hold on 
s1 = scatter(1, 1, 150, 'k', 'o') 
s2 = scatter(1, 2, 150, 'k', '+') 
s3 = scatter(2, 1, 150, 'k', 'x') 
h = legend('Circle', 'Plus', 'X', 'Location', 'NorthEast'); 
set(h, 'FontSize', 14) 
axis([0 3 0 3])
```

The marker size in the scatter and legend is different. How can I increase the marker size of legend entries & makes it similar to that of the scatter plot.

Comment: Can you show us with pictures/code what you mean?

Comment: What is that you don't like about that? I see some BIG markers in my legend.

Comment: @AnderBiguri the `FontSize` property of the legend only controls the text. The marker size in the legend does not change.

Comment: I would like to Increase the marker size same as in the scatter plot!

Comment: My brain has had a flashback and I remember having the same problem. Indeed, its annoying. I didnt solve it at the time.

Comment: I was wrong! I did solve it back at the time ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. Though using `icons` is the same apprach, modifying the `LineWidth` does not affect legends with markers.

Comment: [**Alternative one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818805/one-combined-legend-entry-for-multiple-plots/28819664#28819664) and [**Alternative two**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818805/one-combined-legend-entry-for-multiple-plots/28819664#28819664)

Comment: @thewaywewalk your links are the same

Comment: @excaza true -> [**Alternative two**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600123/how-to-enlarge-legend-symbols?lq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to access the `icons` output of the call to `legend` and modify the `MarkerSize` property of the patch objects that are children of those icons.

Call to `legend`:

```
[h,icons,plots,legend_text] = legend('Circle', 'Plus', 'X', 'Location', 'NorthEast');
```

`icons` is a 6x1 graphics array like so:

```
icons = 

  6x1 graphics array:

  Text     (Circle)
  Text     (Plus)
  Text     (X)
  Group    (Circle)
  Group    (Plus)
  Group    (X)
```

What you need are the elements associated with a `Group`.

If you look at their properties (here `icons(4)`), you get:

```
icons(4)

 Group (Circle) with properties:

    Children: [1x1 Patch]
     Visible: 'on'
     HitTest: 'off'

  Show all properties
```

So there is a patch object associated with it as its child. You want to modify it using for instance

```
icons(Some index).Children.MarkerSize
```

In your case, you need to modify objects 4 to 6:

```
for k = 4:6
icons(k).Children.MarkerSize = 20;
end
```

which outputs:

[image]

you can automate this of course. I used R2015a so I expect the behavior to be the same for R2014b.

Hope this is what you meant!

Comment: Doesn't work in R2015a